# Error in running react-native run-ios on Command Line

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I was working on my React Native project. When I tried to run the **ios** using this command `react-native run-ios` I'm getting this error (See below).

```
error Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65. To debug build logs further, consider building your app with Xcode.app, by opening *.xcworkspace

** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    CompileC /****/ios/build/SykesPHMobile/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/DoubleConversion.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/fixed-dtoa.o /****/ios/Pods/DoubleConversion/double-conversion/fixed-dtoa.cc normal x86_64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    CompileC /****/ios/build/SykesPHMobile/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/DoubleConversion.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/strtod.o /****/ios/Pods/DoubleConversion/double-conversion/strtod.cc normal x86_64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    CompileC /****/ios/build/SykesPHMobile/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/DoubleConversion.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/double-conversion.o /****/ios/Pods/DoubleConversion/double-conversion/double-conversion.cc normal x86_64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    CompileC /****/ios/build/SykesPHMobile/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/DoubleConversion.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/fast-dtoa.o /****/ios/Pods/DoubleConversion/double-conversion/fast-dtoa.cc normal x86_64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(4 failures)
```

However when I run and build the ios project in Xcode directly there's no error I encountered it run successfully the project in simulator. Here's the details of my react native cli

```
System:
    OS: macOS 10.15.2
    CPU: (4) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3210M CPU @ 2.50GHz
    Memory: 165.61 MB / 8.00 GB
    Shell: 3.2.57 - /bin/bash
  Binaries:
    Node: 10.15.1 - /usr/local/bin/node
    npm: 6.13.1 - /usr/local/bin/npm
    Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: iOS 13.2, DriverKit 19.0, macOS 10.15, tvOS 13.2, watchOS 6.1
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: 2.3 AI-162.4069837
    Xcode: 11.2/11B52 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  npmPackages:
    react: 16.9.0 => 16.9.0 
    react-native: 0.61.5 => 0.61.5 
  npmGlobalPackages:
    create-react-native-app: 1.0.0
    react-native-cli: 2.0.1
```

I already tried the following solution below.

1. Delete the Pod folder inside ios and reinstall again.
2. Remove the build folder then run `react-native run-ios`
3. Clean my local cache in Cocoapods and perform the steps one again. Same error that I encountered.

Any ideas how to solve this error.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Removing spaces in my project name resolved this issues. I will mark as answered the question above.

Comment: Can you elaborate what changes you made exactly?

Answer (score 0):

1. delete ios/build
2. watchman watch-del-all
3. rm -rf /tmp/haste-map-react-native-packager-* rm
4. -rf /tmp/metro-bundler-cache-*